# How to get buffer position given line number and column number?

Tags: elisp, point

I'm trying to swap the contents of a region with the text of the same width region below it. I think I should be able to atleast correctly capture the region on the next line using the code below, assuming I can get the positions for them. Any suggestions on how I should implement `pos-at-line-col` or is there already a function to do this?

```
(defun region-selected ()
  "Return a list of the currently selected region if active."
  (if (use-region-p)
      (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (list nil nil)))

(defun column-number-at-pos (pos)
  "Analog to line-number-at-pos."
  (save-excursion (goto-char pos) (current-column)))

(defun tabular-swap-region-down (beg end)
  "Swap the highlighted text with the same region on the next row."
  (interactive (region-selected))
  (let* ((selection (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))
         (line      (line-number-at-pos beg))
         (bcol      (column-number-at-pos beg))
         (ecol      (column-number-at-pos end))
         (next-line (1+ line))
         (next-beg  (pos-at-line-col next-line bcol))
         (next-end  (pos-at-line-col next-line ecol))
         (next-sel  (buffer-substring-no-properties next-beg next-end)))
    (message "Region: %s Beginning column: %s Ending column: %s"
             next-sel (int-to-string bcol) (int-to-string ecol))))
```

Comment: How about using `move-to-column`?  See also `vertical-motion` if you use wrapped lines.  Emacs has stuff built in for transpose lines, etc., if you haven't already checked those out.  *IF* the position is **visible**, you may also wish to experiment with `posn-at-point`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Mouse.html  The other stuff, however, doesn't rely upon point being visible.

Comment: This thread appears to be directly on point to your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2423919/2112489 It cites another link that specifically deals with transposing regions using `move-to-column`:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gnu.emacs.help/dd2R_UV0LVQ/F06ihLb7hKcJ  The thread cites another library that handles this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a version using [`forward-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Lines.html) and [`move-to-column`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Columns.html):

```
(defun pos-at-line-col (l c)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line l)
    (move-to-column c)
    (point)))
```

Note that [`next-error`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html) has to be able to do that, so you might want to start with functions parsing compilation output...