# How to highlight a buffer between given pairs of points?

Tags: highlighting

I have a list that looks like this:

```
(((assoc)
  (start (assoc) (line . 430) (col . 28))
  (end (assoc) (line . 430) (col . 37)))
 ((assoc)
  (start (assoc) (line . 433) (col . 14))
  (end (assoc) (line . 433) (col . 23))))
```

I'd like to highlight all the regions specified by the start/end pairs. I should be able to do this if I had a function that highlighted a region in an emacs buffer, but I see no such function. I checked the hl libray but all the commands seemed to design for interactive use. Is there anything that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)).

You can highlight the text you want in various ways.  One way is to use a regexp, with function (command) `hlt-highlight-regexp-region`. Or if you locate the region to highlight in another way you can use `hlt-highlight-region`.

Or you can use function `hlt-highlight-regions`, which highlights a set of buffer zones, defined by their limit positions.
For example, this highlights buffer positions 1 to 3, 6 to 8, and 12 to 16 using face `highlight`:

```
(hlt-highlight-regions '((1 3) (6 8) (12 16)) 'highlight)
```

(If you also use library [Zones](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Zones) ([`zones.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zones.el)) then you can use `hlt-highlight-regions` interactively, as well as make use of other buffer-zone features.)

In your case, you would apparently just need to convert your information about line and column numbers to buffer positions, then pass the pairs of buffer positions to `hlt-highlight-regions`.

It's a bit unfortunate that your input data is in the form of line and column numbers instead of buffer positions or x-y pixel coordinates.  [Here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8083/105) is code for how to convert line+column data to buffer positions.

Comment: How would I remove the regions created using your function? I know there's a similar `hlt-unhighlight-regions` command, but if the buffer was modified and the points are  no longer the same?

Comment: 1. If you want to unhighlight text between two buffer limits then you need to provide those limits to the unhighlighting function. If you want to use the same buffer limits that you used previously to highlight, save those limits and reuse them. 2. Unhighlighting commands, like highlighting commands, take a `FACE` argument. So you can unhighlight only some particular face across some extent (e.g., the whole buffer), without unhighlighting other faces. 3. This is not the place to document the library - please read the doc.